# PHP no results from post

Tags: php, html

I have a search box which should return results from the database. Code below:

```
    <div style="margin-top:70px;">
<?php include 'inc/search.php'; ?>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">
    <?php 
    if($check_num_rows !== 0) {
        echo '<h3>Results</h3>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo '
        <a href="product.php?product='. $row['link'] .'">
          <div class="row fix">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <img src="files/'. $row['main_image'] .'" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h2>'. $row['item_title'] .'</h2>
                  <h4>'. $row['description'] .'</h4>
              </div>    
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4>Size:<br /> '. $row['size'] .'</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4>&pound;'. $row['price'] .'</h4>
              </div>
          </div>
        </a>';
        }
    } else {
        echo '<h2>Sorry, no items could be found for your search.</h2><h4>Consider buying one new <a href="http://www.scholars-uk.com" target="">here</a>?</h4>';
    } ?>
</div>
```

For this to work I know  `<?php include 'inc/search.php'; ?>` needs to be below the rest of the code but that will break the page layout that I want. Is there a way to have `<?php include 'inc/search.php'; ?>` below the rest of the code but still be executed on the page above so it won't break the layout. Sorry if I didn't explain this very clearly. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can save the results of the search at a `$variable` and than using it wherever you want inside the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store result in a variable. And `echo` it where you want to:

```
<div style="margin-top:70px;">
<?php include 'inc/search.php'; ?>
</div>
<hr>

<div class="container">
    <?php 
    if($check_num_rows !== 0) {
        $result = '<h3>Results</h3>';
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $result .= '
        <a href="product.php?product='. $row['link'] .'">
          <div class="row fix">
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <img src="files/'. $row['main_image'] .'" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-4">
                  <h2>'. $row['item_title'] .'</h2>
                  <h4>'. $row['description'] .'</h4>
              </div>    
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4>Size:<br /> '. $row['size'] .'</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="col-md-2">
                  <h4>&pound;'. $row['price'] .'</h4>
              </div>
          </div>
        </a>';
        }
    } else {
       $result .= '<h2>Sorry, no items could be found for your search.</h2><h4>Consider buying one new <a href="http://www.scholars-uk.com" target="">here</a>?</h4>';
    } ?>
</div>
```

Now you can `echo $result`.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the problem is without knowing the contents of what's in 'inc/search.php' however it does appear that the problem you're having is a result of mixing your display concerns with your model concerns.

You may want to separate your concerns so that they aren't so tightly coupled. A common pattern for this in web development is Model-View-Controller (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). There are many PHP frameworks that help enforce this.